# How to dump and restore correctly a postgresql db from docker

Tags: python, django, postgresql, docker

I stuck with this error when trying to backup and restore my database from a docker django app environment :

[image]

I first did this command to backup my whole DB

```bash
docker exec -t project_final-db-1 pg_dumpall -c -U fred2020 > ./db/dump.sql
```

And then trying to restory with this command

```bash
cat dump.sql | docker exec -i --user fred2020 catsitting-db-1 psql -U fred2020 -d postgres
```

I have two containers, one for my django app named `catsitting-web-1` and one for my postgresql named `catsitting-db-1`.

I don't understand why it gaves me that error, my db user is the same that I specified on the *Dockerfile*.

Any clue ?
For purpose help, here is my docker files configuration :

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.9
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
WORKDIR /code
COPY requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN pip install Pillow
COPY . /code/
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3.9"
    
services:
    db:
    image: postgres
    environment:
        - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
        - POSTGRES_USER=fred2020
        - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=p*******DD
    expose:
        - "5432"
    ports:
        - 5432:5432
    web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
        - .:/code
    ports:
        - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
        - db
```

**requirements.txt**

```
Django>=3.0,<4.0
psycopg2-binary>=2.8
Pillow==8.1.0
```

And that's my process to migrate from laptop1 to laptop2 :

**Installation**
Run a command line go into a root directory and run:

```bash
git clone https://github.com/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

In the command line go into the root directory:

```bash
cd catsitting
```

In the same command line window, run:

```bash
docker-compose build --no-cache
```

In the command line window you need first to migrate the database for Django, run :

```bash
docker-compose run web python manage.py migrate
```

In the command line window then you need to apply the migrations, run :

```bash
docker-compose run web python manage.py makemigrations
```

In the command line window then you need to import database, run :

```bash
cat dump.sql | docker exec -i --user fred2020 catsitting-db-1 psql -U fred2020 -d postgres
```

(for dumping my DB I used `docker exec -t project_final-db-1 pg_dumpall -c -U fred2020 > ./db/dump.sql`)

You can now run:

```bash
docker-compose up
```

Is there something I get wrong ?

Comment: Why are you using different container name for backup and restore db? project_final-db-1 != catsitting-db-1. Also you didn't have to add `-d postgres` for restore, because it's a default table name

Comment: the thing is that I worked in a first laptop where my repository is called "project_final" and I backuped from this docker environnement where my container is named "project_final-db-1" for the postgresql db. 
Now I want to restore that DB in a new laptop because I'm restoring the docker environnement and the whole django app (with db datas...). Is this a problem if the names of the containers are not the same from the laptop1 to laptop2 ?

Comment: The error clearly states that password authentication has failed. Either you have not created the user, either you're not passing the correct password, either you have not set granted proper permissions to that user.

Comment: Hello, in my docker-compose.yml file it is mentionned "POSTGRES_USER=fred2020" and the password on "POSTGRES_PASSWORD" attribute. When I connect through PGADMIN I use the same user and password. Do you think it is my backup command line that it is wrong : `docker exec -t project_final-db-1 pg_dumpall -c -U fred2020 > ./db/dump.sql` . How or where do I need to specify the password when I backup my DB ? Here is a printscreen of my PGADMIN https://imgur.com/a/w9Fh78C

Comment: I tried again in an another laptop and still get this error messages `catsitting-db-1   | 2021-11-27 13:14:40.917 UTC [33] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "fred2020"
catsitting-db-1   | 2021-11-27 13:14:40.917 UTC [33] DETAIL:  User "fred2020" does not have a valid SCRAM secret.` I have granted all groupe membership for user fred2020 in pgadmin. I really stuck...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok sorry folks I found the solution.
I've put that line in my docker-compose.yml:

```
environment:
- POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved !
It was a problem in misconfiguration in the pg_hba.conf inside my docker postgresql
I changed the value from scram-sha-256 to md5 and it works now I can display my webapp with the current db !!

Do you know how to specifie md5 when I build my docker environnement ? by default it puts scram-sha-256

Answer (score 0):

Do you know why when I restore my dump in the new environnement by default in the container the pg_hba.conf set the authentification methode to scram-sha-256 and to do my connection working I need to edit that file and to put the authentification method set to md5 ?

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER        ADDRESS     METHOD
local   all             all                     md5
```